# error: Expected identifier or '('

Tags: ios4, cocos2d-iphone, iphone

in File.h

I have variable are:

```
NSString *Category;
```

in .m and .h

I get this error "Expected identifier or '(' " on this line of code:

------------------------------------.h

```
Category = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectStatement,3)];

[Categoryarray addObject:Category];

Category = [Categoryarray objectAtIndex:i];

sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 3, [Category UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT); //! Receiver type 'Category'(aka 'struct objc_category *') is not Object..
```

Category is not an Object-C class name or alias

---------------------------------------end

and in second class are show red mistake:
-----------------.h sub class

IBOutlet UITextField *Category;

----------------.m sub class

```
if([Category.text isEqualToString:@""] || Category.text == nil){ // ! expect ";" in expression
    Category.text=@" ";
}
```

In code another line not wrong but only this line is wrong.

and im not sure why, can anyone help?

Comment: in scope -----.h to ---end 4 line and in scope if

Comment: everything about Category are show mistake, I don't know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are experiencing a name clash. `Category` is defined in [obj-class.h](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-208/runtime/objc-class.h) like this:

```
typedef struct objc_category *Category;
```

Hence, your error (from your comments):

> Receiver type 'Category'(aka 'struct
>   objc_category *') is not Objective-C
>   class.

**Renaming your instance variable to something else should fix the issue (almost, keep reading).**

Also, your variable is a `NSString` and does not have a property `text`.

```
if([Category.text isEqualToString:@""] || Category.text == nil){
    Category.text=@" ";
}
```

You can invoke those methods on the NSString directly like this:

```
if([myString isEqualToString:@""] || myString == nil) {
    myString = @"";
}
```

Comment: Yes, rename `Category` to something else.

Comment: That's Work!, but How to Category.text to myString.

Comment: I used stringWithFormat. but I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

If "`Category`" is `NSString`, you can directly do

```
if([Category isEqualToString:@""] || Category == nil){ 

}
```

Comment: It show also-> ! Receiver type 'Category'(aka 'struct objc_category *') is not Objective-C class. T-T"

Comment: Have you included the header file of the class which contains Category?

Comment: Sure, Variables except Category are pass.

Comment: In File.h you declared Category as NSString and in File.m, you are doing those database operation and using Category, is this right? Or are you doing the database operations somwehere else in other file?

Comment: First, I used Category NSString doing database operation in .m

and I declared IBOutlet UITextField *Category; for check in sub class .m

Comment: I think the first problem is not understanding the problem itself clearly. You are using Category as NSString in some class (say ClassA) and using it as UITextField in other class which is a subclass of ClassA?

Comment: you right,now I have issue UITextField cann't used by isEqualToString.

Comment: Now I completed all. Thank you for Help.

Answer (score 0):

"**Category**" is **NSString**, So you can directly do

```
if([Category isEqualToString:@""] || Category == nil){ 
  Category = @"";
}
```